# CRC error detection problem

Tags: detection, crc

I need to implement the CRC error detection in my system. I wonder how to 
determine the maximal number of detectable error (and undetectable as well) having the generation polynomial?

Assume that I have got, say, the following g(x) = x^4 + x^3 + 1.
There are 2^15 possible transmissions - the 11-bit words might be protected by this CRC.

How to find the number of transmissions with detectable and undetectable errors?

Thank you for the reply!

Cheers